# I can't able to read the response from the server in angularjs code

Tags: angularjs

I can't able to read the response from the server in angularjs code. in $http methode , but in chrome inspect network option , i can sea the request and response.

My code is

```js
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
}).then(function successCallback(res) {
    console.log('---res', res);
}, function errorCallback(res) {
    console.log('---err', res);
});
```

Comment: Try removing the function names `then(function successCallback(res) {` becomes `then(function(res) {` etc.

Comment: i changes but still i cant able to fetch res data.

Comment: So what are you seeing? You really haven't provided any debugging details

Comment: nothing is printing in the console , In debugging its just skipping success callback function , But in network request console , its printing the request and response . so how can i debug next

Comment: I find it hard to believe that *nothing* is printing in the console.

Comment: $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: data,
                responseType: 'arraybuffer',
                transformResponse: appendTransform($http.defaults.transformResponse, function(value) {
                    return doTransform(value);
            })
            });  this has worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        transformResponse: appendTransform($http.defaults.transformResponse, function(value) {
            return doTransform(value);
        })
});
```

above code worked for me